# Multiple Datasource on StringBoot Multimodule project

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, microservices

I have a Springboot project organized in different modules.
This is the main pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.cmw</groupId>
  <artifactId>bo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>bo</name>
  <url>https://www.test.com</url>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</mapstruct.version>
    <org.lombok.version>1.18.18</org.lombok.version>
  </properties>

  <modules>
    <module>bo_libs</module>
    <module>bo_basis_lib</module>
    <module>bo_basis</module>
    <module>bo_api_lib</module>
    <module>bo_api</module>
    <module>bo_ui</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencies>

    ...

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

I'm trying to have each module connect to a different database.

For the bo_basis module I have created this configuration class

```
package com.cmw.bo.basis.config;

import com.cmw.bo.basis.repositories.SampleDataPopulator;
import com.cmw.bo.common.config.DataAccessConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.hibernate.boot.SchemaAutoTooling;
import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@Profile("development")
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
        "com.cmw.bo.basis.repositories"
})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class DevelopmentDataAccessConfig extends DataAccessConfig {

    @Value(value = "${jdbc.url}")
    private String jdbcUrl;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        final HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();

        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(String.format("%s/bo_basis", jdbcUrl));
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", true);
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", 250);
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", 2048);
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", true);
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("useLocalSessionState", true);
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("useLocalTransactionState", true);
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("rewriteBatchedStatements", true);
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("cacheResultSetMetadata", true);
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("cacheServerConfiguration", true);
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("elideSetAutoCommits", true);
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("maintainTimeStats", false);
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("useSSL", false);
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("characterEncoding", "utf8");
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("useUnicode", "true");
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("serverTimezone", "UTC");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SampleDataPopulator sampleDataPopulator() {

        return new SampleDataPopulator();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean getShowSql() {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected SchemaAutoTooling getSchemaAutoTooling() {

        return SchemaAutoTooling.VALIDATE;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getPackagesToScan() {

        return new String[]{
                "com.cmw.bo.basis.entities",
                "com.cmw.bo.common.models.entities"
        };
    }


    @Override
    protected String getDatabasePlatform() {

        return MySQL8Dialect.class.getCanonicalName();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getName() {

        return "basisJpaManager";
    }

}
```

The DataAccessConfig class:

```
@Configuration
public abstract class DataAccessConfig {

    @Bean
    @DependsOn({"flyway"})
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(getShowSql());
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(getDatabasePlatform());

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setValidationMode(ValidationMode.CALLBACK);
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan(getPackagesToScan());
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO, getSchemaAutoTooling().name().toLowerCase());

        // To avoid: Entity manager factory name (default) is already registered.
        // If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'
        properties.put("hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name", getName());
        factory.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());

        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Database migration")
    public Flyway flyway() {

        Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure()
                .dataSource(dataSource())
                .validateOnMigrate(true)
                .baselineOnMigrate(true)
                .outOfOrder(false).load();

        flyway.migrate();

        return flyway;
    }

    protected abstract boolean getShowSql();

    protected abstract SchemaAutoTooling getSchemaAutoTooling();

    protected abstract String[] getPackagesToScan();

    protected abstract String getDatabasePlatform();

    protected abstract String getName();

    public abstract DataSource dataSource();
}
```

For the bo_ui module the configuration class is the same (apart from the jdbc connection url of course)

The problem is that (obviously) if I keep the configuration classes the same name I get a ConflictingBeanDefinitionException. If I rename the classes differently, one of the two connections is ignored.

How would you solve this problem that was not taken into consideration in the design phase?

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to create different datasource from the same module, or are you looking to connect multiple databases from the same module? Your question is quite confusing. Can you please elaborate more on this? Multi project still means multi project where you can define your datasource as per your module, which is independent to your modules.

Comment: The project is organized into different modules, which will eventually produce a single jar. Each module will have to connect to a different database. Please check the pom.xml I posted

Answer (score 1):

You can apply as a way to dynamically determine the actual DataSource based on the current context.

I think is similar to what you ask: [Spring's AbstractRoutingDatasource](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source)

good coding! ¯_(ツ)_/¯